# MySQL 3 table join

Tags: sql, mysql

I have data to get listings according to their location.  The locations are mapped in a location map table.  The structure basically looks like:

```
listings
  -id
  -title
  etc.

locations
  -id
  -location_name
  etc. 

location_map
  -listing_id
  -location_id
```

When I want to list the listings according to their location, I am using the following SQL.  Basically, I have the location id, and I then can find the listings that are in that location.  I use the DISTINCT so that I don't get duplicate location results.

This works, but I'm wondering if this is a good way to do it, as I need to use DISTINCT.  Is there a better, more preferred way of doing something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT LS.title, LS.id, LS.url, LS.description

        FROM listings LS

            JOIN location_map MAP ON LS.id = MAP.listing_id
            JOIN locations LOC ON LOC.id = MAP.location_id

        WHERE LOC.id = 123

        ORDER BY LS.title;
```

Comment: Why are you getting duplicates?  Is there more than one row in location_map for each listing/location combination?

Comment: This code works (I don't get duplicates), I'm just not sure if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: what he means is, what kind of dupes do you get if you DON'T use `DISTINCT`?  From what you have showed of your data model you shouldn't get dupes...

Comment: I see what you're saying. So, I probably have separate problem with having multiple listing/location combinations that are the same.  I should have checked that first.  The answer below, was also very helpful for me.  As I get more data, I'm going to test which statement is most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT LS.title, LS.id, LS.url, LS.description
FROM listings LS
WHERE 
LS.id IN (
   SELECT LM.listing_id
   FROM location_map LM
   WHERE LM.location_id = 123 )
```

This eliminates the join to location.

I'm not sure what the DISTINCT problem is.  If you've identified a single location, why would there be duplicates?

Comment: Thanks very much.  Your statement works, and is much simpler.  I had just read that in general it's better to use a sub-select statement, rather than using DISTINCT, but I couldn't figure out how.  Seeing your solution it is very straightforward.